# MS Access: Using Single form to enter query parameters in MS access

Tags: mysql, forms, ms-access

compliment of the day.
Based on the previous feedback received,

After creating a Ticket sales database in MS Access. I want to use a single form to Query the price of a particular ticket at a particular month and have the price displayed back in the form in a text field or label.

Below are sample tables and used query

**CompanyTable**

```
CompID    CompName
   A        Ann
   B        Bahn
   C        Can
   KK       Seven
   -        --
```

**TicketTable**

```
 TicketCode    TicketDes

 10            Two people
 11            Monthly
 12            Weekend
 14            Daily
```

**TicketPriceTable**

```
 ID    TicketCode    Price    ValidFrom

  1    10            $35.50    8/1/2010
  2    10            $38.50    8/1/2011
  3    11            $20.50    8/1/2010
  4    11            $25.00    11/1/2011
  5    12            $50.50    12/1/2010
  6    12            $60.50    1/1/2011
  7    14            $15.50    2/1/2010
  8    14            $19.00    3/1/2011
  9    10            $40.50    4/1/2012
```

**Used query:**

```
SELECT TicketPriceTable.Price
 FROM TicketPriceTable
 WHERE (((TicketPriceTable.ValidFrom)=[DATE01]) AND ((TicketPriceTable.TicketCode)=[TCODE01]));
```

- In MS Access, a mini boxes pops up to enter the parameters when running the query. How can I use a single form to enter the parameters for [DATE01] and [TCODE01]. and the price displayed in the same form in a textfield (For further calculations).

Such as 'Month' field equals to input to [DATE01] parameter
'Ticket Code' equals to input for [TCODE01] parameter
Textfield equals to output of the query result (Ticket price)

- If possible, I would like to use only the Month and Year in this format MM/YYYY.The day is not necessarry. How can I achieve it in MS Access?

If any question, please don't hesitate to ask
Thanks very much for your time and anticipated feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Entering up to 300 different types of tickets

<sup>Answer to your comment referring to [Accessing data from a ticket database, based on months in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11037918/880990))</sup>

You can use Cartesian products to create a lot of records. If you select two tables in a query but do not join them, the result is a Cartesian product, which means that every record from one table is combined with every record from the other.

Let's add a new table called `MonthTable`

```
MonthNr    MonthName
    1      January
    2      February
    3      March
  ...      ...
```

Now if you combine this table containing 12 records with your `TicketTable` containing 4 records, you will get a result containing 48 records

```sql
SELECT M.MonthNr, M.MonthName, T.TicketCode, T.TicketDes
FROM MonthTable M, TicketTable T
ORDER BY M.MonthNr, T.TicketCode
```

You get something like this

```
MonthNr    MonthName   TicketCode  TicketDes
    1      January         10      Two people
    1      January         11      Monthly
    1      January         12      Weekend
    1      January         14      Daily
    2      February        10      Two people
    2      February        11      Monthly
    2      February        12      Weekend
    2      February        14      Daily
    3      March           10      Two people
    3      March           11      Monthly
    3      March           12      Weekend
    3      March           14      Daily
  ...      ...            ...      ...
```

You can also get the price actually valid for a ticket type like this

```sql
SELECT TicketCode, Price, ActualPeriod AS ValidFrom
FROM (SELECT TicketCode, MAX(ValidFrom) AS ActualPeriod
      FROM TicketPriceTable
      WHERE ValidFrom <= Date
      GROUP BY TicketCode) X
    INNER JOIN TicketPriceTable T
        ON X.TicketCode = T.TicketCode AND X.ActualPeriod=T.ValidFrom
```

The `WHERE ValidFrom <= Date` is in case that you entered future prices.

Here the subquery selects the actually valid period, i.e. the `ValidFrom` that applies for each `TicketCode`. If you find sub-selects a bit confusing, you can also store them as query in Access or as view in MySQL and base a subsequent query on them. This has the advantage that you can create them in the query designer.

Consider not creating all your 300 records physically, but just getting them dynamically from a Cartesian product.

I let you put all the pieces together now.

Comment: It's working well. There's error while running the last, price query.`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TicketCode WHERE ValidFrom <= Date'` If I could fix the `MM/YYYY` but maybe stored as `MMDDYYYY` then no more problem on this. My Form/SQL is: `WHERE (((TicketPriceTable.TicketCode)=[Forms]![SumForm]![cboTicketCode]) AND ((TicketPriceTable.ValidFrom)<=([Forms]![SumForm]![cboMonth] & "/01/" & [Forms]![SumForm]![cboYear])) AND ((TicketPriceTable.ValidTILL)>=([Forms]![SumForm]![cboMonth] & "/01/" & [Forms]![SumForm]![cboYear])));
`Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry. I inverted the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses. First WHERE, then GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the values in the form fields by using expressions like: [Forms]![NameOfTheForm]![NameOfTheField]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, It was helpful. Please do you have an optimal solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037918/accessing-data-from-a-ticket-database-based-on-months-in-ms-access ? The ticket prices are the same for the whole year between 08/2010 to 08/2011. and entering 300 types of tickets on monthly bases would give huge data redundancy. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In Access Forms you can set the `RecordSource` to be a query, not only  a table. This can be either the name of a stored query or a SQL statement. This allows you to have controls bound to different tables through this query.

You can also place subforms on the main form that are bound to other tables than the main form.

You can also display the result of an expression in a `TextBox` by setting the `ControlSource` to an expression by starting with an equal sign

```
=DLookUp("Price", "TicketPriceTable", "TicketCode=" & Me!cboTicketCode.Value)
```

---

You can set the Format of a TextBox to `MM\/yyyy` or use the format function

```
s = Format$(Now, "MM\/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It was really helpful.. Does you have optimal alternative to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037918/accessing-data-from-a-ticket-database-based-on-months-in-ms-access ? The answer was helpful but the problem is. I have up to 300 different types of tickets. Entering each ticket 12 time for a year and 36 times for 2010 2011 and 2012 will be a huge data redundancy. Is there anyway i can group the prices on yearly bases? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I couldn't format the textbox as s = Format$(Now, "MM\/yyyy")

Comment: What happens? It works for me and yields "06/2012". (By entering `?Format$(Now, "MM\/yyyy")`<Enter> in the Immediate window in Access.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. where exactly to enter the CMD? I entered it in the `Control Source` of the Date's `TextBox`but it didn't work. The MS Access date format is `MMDDYYYY (08/1/2011)` but the user have to enter only `MMYYYY (08/2011)` and a `TicketCode` to get the actual price of the ticket at the entered `MM/YYYY`. Or if possible, the user only have to enter 082011 in the date's TextBox but stored as 08/1/2011 in the `ValidFrom` Frield.

Comment: `TextBox` has a `Format` property where you can enter the format string `MMyyyy`.

Comment: thanks once again. From the date format, I could only see `MMDDYYYY` regardless of if it is General, Long or Short Date format. But when I do type in only `MM/YYYY`in the date textbox, it automatically change to `MM/01/YYYY`. I guess i will manage it like that unless it is really important that the `DD` is not required.. Thanks alot!

Comment: The TextBox must either be unbound or bound to a table column of Date/Time type. If the column is of type `Text` this will not work!